# Anyone know how to find out what callbacks are available for Safari?

Tags: safari, applescript

I'd like to do some basic automation of Safari from Applescript (unless someone knows a better way). From web searching, I've found that there is a callback named page_loaded() but there must be other callbacks that I can leverage. More importantly, I can't see how to figure out that even page_loaded() is available. It doesn't show up in the Applescript dictionary for Safari, for example.
So where can I find a list of callbacks that I can use in Applescript?

Comment: Actually there are no built-in callbacks at all. `page_loaded()` is an AppleScript repeat loop polling a result of a custom javascript function.

Comment: Maybe I should have used the term "handler" instead --- I was under the impression that some functions in Applescript could be invoked from the outside (hence my use of the term callback).  I do however understand what you're saying about page_loaded but where is it defined? If it's a call to Safari then why doesn't it show up in the Safari dictionary?

Comment: Yes, there are event handlers in Mail and Messages but not in Safari. `page_loaded` is something custom defined by the scripter in a `do javascript` line, it's not in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So where can I find a list of callbacks that I can use in Applescript?

First of all, AppleScript doesn't have asynchronous callback handlers but some applications may invoke specific handlers. They're not callback handlers, but handlers that are invoked by an application or the system and not by the user.

To make the answer complete, you can find application specific handlers in the application's dictionary. For example a mail rule handler can be found in the Mail application dictionary. Just drag and drop Mail.app file on ScriptEditor and the dictionary will be opened. There you'll find `perform mail action with messages` which is an handler that will be called if the script will be launched by a mail rule.

Handlers in the global namespace needs to be looked up in the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). There you'll find the `adding folder items to` handler which will be called when the script is launched by folder actions (and the user performed the associated action).

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what else to call code in Applescript that start with "on ..."

Comment: (Sigh, why can't I delete an unfinished comment). OK, I understand handlers but where do I find the handlers for Safari? I found the 'perform' handler for Mail but if I didn't know the name beforehand, how would I be able to find that handler?  It's just defined as a command and unless you read the entire description, it's not distinguishable as a "handler" from other "commands". If I look at the list of Commands for Safari, none of them look like they're handlers for any Safari events.  I'm wondering if I would be better off just doing everything with GreaseMonkey scripts?

Comment: You're right and it's one of the many quirks in AppleScript. The dictionary doesn't make a clear distinction between commands and handlers. Fwiw the problem is the sdef file format which has no supporty for handlers. But also enumerator value won't be shown in dictionaries and coercion handlers also lacks from it. It's been incomplete for 25 years and too bad Apple still haven't solved this.

Comment: I guess AppleScript is just not the right solution for anything anymore. I had also been using it to manipulate text in MS Powerpoint and when I tried to do the same thing with Keynote I discovered the functionality I needed wasn't there. (sigh)